# Why is Homebrew finding phantom directories?

Tags: macos, homebrew

I'm running Homebrew on macOS High Sierra 10.13.6. I use a bash alias `brewup` to periodically check on my installation.  `brewup` is defined as below:

`alias brewup= 'brew update; brew upgrade; brew prune; brew cleanup; brew doctor'`

Recently, when running `brewup`, the output from the `brew prune` portion of the command has been:

`Pruned 0 symbolic links and 2 directories from /usr/local`.

Every single time I run the `brewup`command, even after restarting, hand checking `/usr/local` for excess directories, recreating the `brewup` alias, and completely reinstalling Homebrew and all my packages, I  always get the output `Pruned 0 symbolic links and 2 directories from /usr/local`.

The mystery deepenes even further, because when I run just `brew prune`, I get, as expected, no pruned results whatsoever. Something in the order of the commands contained in `brewup` is causing phantom excess directories to appear, over, and over, and over again.

Can someone help me exorcise these phantom directories?

Comment: If you put a sleep 2 between each command or an echo statement, can you isolate which of the steps is causing the hiccup? I’m excited to learn something here.

Comment: What happens if you run them one command at a time? What is the output of each command?

Answer (score 0):

Try `brew prune --verbose` to see which directories are removed.